# ActiveMQ queued messages dequeue with no consumer

Tags: activemq-classic

I have recently started using ActiveMQ 5.8. I have the default activemq.xml setup and am doing some simple testing with the ActiveMQ web admin. When I send a message to a queue through the ui, the queue will show a pending message for about 5 seconds, then the message will get dequeued. There are no consumers set up on this queue. Why is the message not staying in the queue? In older versions of ActiveMQ, doing this same procedure, the message will remain in the queue, as expected. Did something change with 5.8?

Comment: Do you set a time to live when creating the messages? Can you observe the message details, including their expiration? Sounds like that might be the problem. I use 5.10 at the moment and have not been able to observe this behavior with the default installation.

Comment: I installed ActveMQ 5.10.2 and it works as expected. Messages stay in the queue, without setting time to live or any other attributes. This may have been caused by a bad 5.8 install.

Comment: good to hear that. GL

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me recently. Check activemq.xml for

```
<plugins>
    <timeStampingBrokerPlugin zeroExpirationOverride="1000" ttlCeiling="60000" futureOnly="true"/>
</plugins>
```

zeroExpirationOverride="1000" would automatically expire any message after one second without any consumer being attached.